# Getting Rxjs Observable of data returned in http call promise

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I am trying to use ngx-pagination but facing few issues. I am pretty new to angular 2 and don't know much about observables and subscribers.

I have a service which makes http calls and returns the data:

```
getData(path: string, page: number=1) : Promise<IData[]> {

  return this.http.get(path+'&pageNumber='+page)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json() as IData[];
                    });
}
```

I am consuming this data in my component:

```
getDataValues(page: number) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.asyncData = this.getAsyncData(this.queryPath, page)
        .do(res => {
            this.total = res.total;
            this.p = page;
            this.loading = false;
        })
        .map(res => res.items);
}

getAsyncData(path: string, page: number): Observable<any> {
     return Observable
    .of({
        items: this.repository.getData(path, page),
        total: this.dataValues.length
    });
}
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<div class="list">
<div>
    <article class="entity" *ngFor="let data of asyncData | async | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }">

    </article>
</div>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="getDataValues($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
```

I know this is not correct since I need to wait for the promise to resolve but I don't know how to do that. ngx-pagination expects Observable so `asyncData` needs to be an `Observable`

Comment: Control flow becomes messy when you're mixing observables and promises. Usually this happens when a dev isn't comfortable enough with RxJS. Don't do that unless you really need this and stick to common denominator (observables). Btw, code above won't work as expected, in getAsyncData it's expected that `items` are values, but they are a promise of values (or an observable of values, if you will get rid of toPromise, as the answer suggests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the type signature for the 'get' method of the old Angular http service (the one you are using, the newer one is called HttpClient), you'll see that it returns an Observable of type 'Response'.

```
 get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
```

So simply removing the .toPromise() and .then methods from the get call will leave you with the Observable.